# Graphically detect a control on a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, controls

so i have this form where users can drag and drop user controls(that are only picture boxes). They can't put a control on another one, as they have to place the pictures in order. Here's my current code: 
"TempControl" is the object that is checked in the "for each" loop
"Control" is the object that just got dropped by the user

```
        ' vertical check: there's two lines possible
            If Control.Top < 200 Then
                Control.Top = 70
            Else
                Control.Top = 240
            End If
        ' horizontal check:
        For Each tempControl As MyUSerControl In MyArray
                If tempControl.Left < Control.Left And tempControl.Left + tempControl.Width > Control.Left Then    'If the left limit of the moved object is in the fix object                   
                        Control.Left = tempControl.Left + tempControl.Width + 5    'Put it on the fix object's right side
                End If

                If tempControl.Left > Control.Left And tempControl.Left < Control.Left + Control.Width Then  'If the right limit of the moved object is in the fix object        
                        Control.Left = tempControl.Left - Control.Width - 5    'Put it on the left side
                End If
        Next
```

It works fine (for now), but i was wondering if there was any way to "graphically" verify the positions, like a function that checks if the form under the Control is free ?

If not, is there a more optimized algorithm for this kind of things ? What are your thoughts about it ?
Thanks !

Comment: How many controls are you going to have? I'd say, if there are less than 100, it is not worth investing time into making this more efficient. Also, you should consider the case when there is simply no room at the dropped location (between two other controls).

Comment: Maybe something with control.Bounds and even control.Bounds.IntersectsWith?

Comment: Maybe, use a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: I apparently can't use `control.bounds`, even after using `control.setbounds`...
Also for the TableLayoutPanel is quite hard to use, but it has some potential, i'll see if i can do something with it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but let's see if this one helps.

[GetChildAtPoint(Point)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getchildatpoint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

> Retrieves the child control at a specified location.

**Example:**

```
Dim controlAtPoint = myForm.GetChildAtPoint(anyPoint)
```

Comment: It actually works pretty nice, thanks !
 I used `If GetChildAtPoint(New Point(Control.Left - 1, Control.Top)) IsNot Nothing Then` for the left side, with the -1 so i don't get the control the user just dropped, and `If GetChildAtPoint(New Point(Control.Left + Control.Width, Control.Top)) IsNot Nothing Then` for the right side, for some reason i don't need +1 here...
Also i had to use `New point` as i can't make `location.offset` work (it says"does't return any value").

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to use Control's Location to get the same control, I mean this `GetChildAtPoint(New Point(Control.Left + Control.Width, Control.Top))` or am I missing something here?.

Comment: I use this line to test the right side of the control the user just dropped, to see if there is something under it. Apparently nothing is detected with this condition if there's nothing behind it, i thought I would need a +1 (like for the left side).